# Can't switch language in RDP login to Ubuntu window

Tags: language-support, rdp

I want to connect to Ubuntu through RDP from Windows 10, but I can't type username and password, because I can't switch language to English.

Tried Alt+Shift, Ctrl+Shift, Ctrl+Alt, Alt+CapsLock, Ctrl+CapsLock

Login window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuIOh.png